# deploy erc721 contracts from a simple or factory contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix, openzeppelin, erc721

I want to deploy erc721 contracts from a simple  factory contract and i have this error  when I try to upload NFT - "transfer to non ERC721Receiver implementer", "data"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWY6z.png)

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;

import "./ezeynftFactory.sol";

contract ezeNFT {
    uint256 public tokenCounter;
     constructor(){
    tokenCounter = 201;
}

  function _mintNewNFT( string memory name, string memory symbol, string memory tokenUri)public{
     uint256 newTokenId = tokenCounter;
     ezeynftFactory nfts = new ezeynftFactory(name,symbol,tokenUri,newTokenId);
     tokenCounter += 1;
  }
 }
```

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;
import "../ERC721/ERC721.sol";


contract ezeynftFactory is ERC721 {
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol,string memory tokenURI,uint tokenID) 
     ERC721(name,symbol)
    {
        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenID);
        _setTokenURI(tokenID,tokenURI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OpenZeppelin [_safeMint()](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.6.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L248) function tries to invoke [onERC721Received()](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.6.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L394-L395) on the receiver if the receiver is a contract (which your `ezeNFT` is). And reverts the transaction if it doesn't receive the expected response (which doesn't receive, so it reverts).

There are two solutions to your problem.

1. Either implement the `onERC721Received()` function on your `ezeNFT` contract (the token receiver), returning the expected response. See `ERC721TokenReceiver` interface in the [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) standard definition for more info.

```
contract ezeNFT {
    uint256 public tokenCounter;

    constructor(){
        tokenCounter = 201;
    }

    function _mintNewNFT( string memory name, string memory symbol, string memory tokenUri) public {
        uint256 newTokenId = tokenCounter;
        ezeynftFactory nfts = new ezeynftFactory(name,symbol,tokenUri,newTokenId);
        tokenCounter += 1;
    }

    function onERC721Received(address _operator, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes _data) external returns(bytes4) {
        // TODO validate if you want to accept tokens only from certain collections

        // return the expected response
        return bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"));
    }
}
```

2. Or use the [_mint()](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.6.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L280) function, instead of `_safeMint()`, which doesn't perform the `onERC721Received()` call on the token receiver. So you won't have to implement it on `ezeNFT`.

```
contract ezeynftFactory is ERC721 {
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol,string memory tokenURI,uint tokenID) 
     ERC721(name,symbol)
    {
        _mint(msg.sender, tokenID); // `_mint()` instead of `_safeMint()`
        _setTokenURI(tokenID,tokenURI);
    }
}
```